# What is the minimal version of Traefik required for kubernetes API v 1.22?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, traefik

We have inherited a kubernetes application on GCP with a Traefik ingress controller, running an old version of traefik (`traefik:v1.7.18-alpine`).  Google cloud is forcing kubernetes upgrades to `v1.22` soon and we're getting GCP warnings that traefik is using deprecated k8s APIs.

[image]

Without getting into the weeds, does anybody know what the minimal version of traefik is that would be compatible with kubernetes 1.22?  According to this thread, it seems it's `traefik 2.X` at least - https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/8343.

Wondering also if it's possible to configure traefik 1.X to not use this API somehow?  Have no idea where/why this deprecated API is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes API v1.22 requires atleast Traefik v2.5 and above as [some APIs are deprecated in the Kubernetes version 1.22](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#ingressclass-v122), as most of them were former Beta (v1beta1) APIs. In v2.5, the [Traefik CRDs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd/#definitions) have been updated to support the new API version apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 as the Beta API version of IngressClass is no longer served as of version 1.22.

The support of the networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 API Version will stop in Kubernetes v1.22.

You can refer to these documentation for more information about [Deprecation Warnings](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#ingressclass-v122) , [Traefik v2 minor migrations](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v2/#v24-to-v25) & [Migration from v1 to v2](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/#migration-guide-from-v1-to-v2)

I hope this answered your queries. Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Traefik 2.0 or later is required for Kubernetes API v1.22; I couldn't find a reference to that in the docs on a quick search. However, here's the Traefik 2.0 release blog: https://traefik.io/blog/traefik-2-0-6531ec5196c2/

There's also a migration guide https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/
and a migration tool, but you might need to evalute if this is helpful: https://github.com/traefik/traefik-migration-tool